# NestJS TCP Microservice is returning nothing on Packet Sender

Tags: typescript, tcp, nestjs, microservices, tcpserver

I implemented a TCP micro service in nestjs trying to follow the documentation and I'm struggling trying to test the application, I found this app on google PacketSender and they prove to me that the request is working normally, because I got a log on prompt about the request, but I'm not receiving on ASCII, anyone knows what I miss?

**main.ts**

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const config = new ConfigService().get();
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice(MainModule, {
    transport: config.authMS.transport,
    options: {
      host: config.authMS.options.host,
      port: Number(config.authMS.options.port),
    },
  } as TcpOptions);
  await app.listen();
}
bootstrap();
```

**main.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(configMainModulesService.getTypeOrmConfig()),
    AuthModule,
  ],
})
export class MainModule {}
```

**auth.controller.ts**

```
@MessagePattern('getUser')
  async user(data: { login: string; token: string }): Promise<any> {
    const res = await this.authService.getUser(data);
    console.log('ress =>', res);
    return res;
  }
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
public async getUser(data: any): Promise<any> {
    const tokenExists = await this.authRepository.findOne({
      where: { token: data.token },
    });

    if (tokenExists) {
      const user = await this.authRepository.findOne({
        where: { login: data.login },
      });
      if (!user) {
        return {
          status: HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
          message: 'user_search_by_credentials_not_found',
          user: null,
        };
      }
      return {
        status: HttpStatus.OK,
        message: 'user_search_by_credentials_success',
        user: this.toPublicUser(user),
      };
    } else {
      return {
        status: HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
        message: 'user_search_by_credentials_token_invalid',
        user: null,
      };
    }
  }
```

**Packet Sender App**
[image]

**Console**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and finally I made it!

you need to add "id" key to your request ASCII string

```
61#{"pattern":"sum","id":"ce51ebd3-32b1-4ae6-b7ef-e018126c4cc4"}
```